# How can I use XNA with Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows?

Tags: xna, c#

http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

I downloaded the current version of Visual Studio to develop Windows Phone apps, but I don't know how to add XNA. I tried to install XNA, but it's not working with Visual Studio.

How can I use XNA with Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[How install XNA 4.0 on Visual Studio 2013](https://msxna.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20install%20XNA%204.0%20on%20Visual%20Studio%202013&referringTitle=Documentation)

1. [Download XNA 4.0 Refresh](https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases) (Visual Studio 2013)
2. Unzip archive
3. Install DirectX from the archive
4. Install Xna Framework 4.0 Redistribution from the archive
5. Install Xna Game Studio 4.0 Platform Tools from the archive
6. Install Xna Game Studio 4.0 Shared from the archive
7. Install XNA Game Studio 4.0.vsix from the archive

Comment: I recently found that codeplex project, extremely useful, no more installing VS 2010 after installing 2013 on new machines to install XNA.

Comment: Thanx. It's working.

Comment: I read somewhere about some other step you had to do if you wanted to do this on Windows 8. Is that true? If so, what is that step?

Comment: The above worked fine for me on Windows 8. However since XNA is no longer supported I would recommend MonoGame or (My personal favorite)FNA as an alternative. Identical framework so all XNA tutorials would still be applicable.  https://github.com/flibitijibibo/FNA

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using XNA Refresh would be to use the following script to install XNA for you. It will automatically build part of VS 2010 temporarily, as I can only assume Refresh is doing, then delete it after it has installed XNA.

This script (both 64 and 32 bit versions) can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/rbwhitaker/xna-beyond-vs-2010/downloads), and only requires Windows Powershell, which should be preinstalled on all modern Windows versions.

(Disclaimer: this is not my script, but has worked successfully for me and others in the past. Happy Coding!)

Comment: This script also has a version for Visual Studio 2015 at that download link. Just download and open the .htm file to get the script